# Wake-On-Lan (WoL) not turning my pc on when used through WAN from a full shutdown (Wake-On-Wan)

Tags: lan, wake-on-lan, wan

My pc won't turn on from a full shutdown when trying over WAN, but the protocol works when trying to wake the pc from sleep-mode over WAN and when trying to turn it on from a full shutdown over LAN. The packages are coming through, as it can be indicated by the fact that it wakes from sleep-mode, and are observable using Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

If your router does not remember your PC's MAC address (that is, if it does not have a persistent static ARP mapping for it), then it will not be able to deliver those packets from the WAN to your PC.

If your PC is deeply powered down, its WOL-capable NIC is probably not replying to ARP requests from the router, so if the router forgot your PC's MAC address, it doesn't have a way to get it, so it doesn't have a way to address those incoming packets to your PC at the Ethernet layer.

Set a static ARP mapping for your PC on your router, and try again. Note that many routers do not give you an easy way to do this in their web-based admin UIs. You might need to find a way to get to a shell, or you might have to load aftermarket open source Linux firmware on your router, or you might have to replace your router with one that supports some solution for entering static ARP mappings.

Comment: I'm currently using my ISP router, and it doesn't allow me to set a static ARP mapping, guess I'll go buy another one and use the current one just as a modem. I'll get some custom firmware probably, any router recommendations?

Comment: Actually no, my pc is ARP mapped: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Sh0oJTl.png). Found a way to see it in the router support settings.

Comment: @elJaberJaber That screenshot looks like the current dynamic table, not a list of persistent static mappings. Entries in a typical dynamic ARP table time out in a couple minutes. So a few minutes after shutting down your PC, it will probably disappear from that list. It would be an interesting test to see if packets from the WAN can successfully wake the PC while it's still showing in the dynamic ARP table. By the way, when in full shutdown mode, do you still see a link light on your switch port and/or NIC?

Comment: @Spliff thanks for the insight, you're right about the ARP mapping, I've managed to install OpenWRT on a Mi WiFi R3G, and now I'm trying to set up a static ARP to my computer's IP, didn't managed to do it so far, when deeply powered down my and the light on my Ethernet port is still up even when the machine is completely off. Thank you for the help, in case of any progress I'll let you know. I didn't managed to find a guide on how to setup a static ARP mappping on OpenWRT...

Comment: @elJaberJaber Thanks for the followup. It's always nice to know if I helped someone. OpenWrt is Linux which is Unix-like, so even if it doesn't have a web-GUI for setting static ARP mappings, you should be able to do it the Unix way of getting a root shell and doing `arp -s …`. That would last until reboot. To persist across reboots, you could add a command like that to one of your system's startup scripts (a.k.a. "RC" scripts). The particular ways to do this can vary from one Unix-like OS to another, and even from one Linux distro to another.